# Rendering action based on (random) route name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a controller action that renders a random route from a set of given route names, *without a redirect*.

I know the method `render controller: name, action: name` but rendering fails because it tries to find a template on it's own instead of letting the target action determine the template.

Here is my code:

```
def random
  # create basic route names
  route_names = %w(root route1 route2)

  # get route path
  path = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send("#{route_names.sample}_path")

  # {controller: name, action: name, param: val}
  action_config = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(path, {:method => :get})

  # doesn't work
  # fails with Missing template application/*action name*
  return render action_config

  # doesnt work
  # require 'open-uri' 
  # render html: open("http://localhost:3000/#{path}") { |io| io.read }

  # doesn't work
  # require 'net/http'
  # require 'uri'
  # render html: Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/#{path}"))

  # doesnt work
  # ctrl = (action_config[:controller].camelize + "Controller").constantize.new
  # ctrl.request = request
  # ctrl.response = response
  # ctrl.send(action_config[:action])

  # works, but not for Derailed
  # redirect_to path

  # works but not for Derailed, since the server doesn't parse the <iframe>
  #render html: "
  #  <iframe 
  #    src='#{path}' 
  #    width='100%' 
  #    height='100%' 
  #    style='overflow: visible; border: 0;'></iframe>
  #  <style>body {margin: 0;}</style>".html_safe
end
```

Could anyone make the `render` work properly?

**background**

I'm trying to debug a memory leak in my Rails app. I'm using the Derailed gem that retrieves a path from my app 10.000 times. Derailed only supports hitting a single path. So, to actually mimic site usage I'm trying to implement an action that renders a random route from a set of given routes. Derailed allows me to use a real webserver like Puma, but that configuration doesn't follow redirects, so I need Rails to render without a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write middleware for this:

```
class RandomMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    route_names = %w(/ /route1 /route2)
    if env['PATH_INFO'] == '/random'
      env['PATH_INFO'] = route_names.sample
    end

    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

and then insert this middleware in the stack (in `config/application.rb`):

```
config.middleware.use RandomMiddleware
```

Comment: had to adjust it to 
    # get route path
        path = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send("#{route_names.sample}_path")

    if env['PATH_INFO'] == '/_random'
      env['PATH_INFO'] = path
    end

but totally worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open new app session inside controller, render action there and return the result:

```
session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
session.get '/'
render html: session.body
```

Comment: Gives a ```ThreadError in ApplicationController#_random```
```deadlock; recursive locking``` on ```session.get```

Comment: Yes, it was bad idea, this is usually used in tests/console, see my another answer